# Vector instantiation with WebGL shaders

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

Probably a simple question but I'm learning how WebGL shaders work. My understanding is a vec4 should be composed as something like vec4(0.5) or vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5) or vec4(vec2(0.5), vec2(0.5)) for example, so why does this example seem to work? It contains a vec4 inside a vec2. I'm also using Three.js.

`vec4 myVec = vec4(vec2(0.5), vec2(0.5, vec4(0.5)));`

But this doesn't work:

`vec4 myVec = vec4(vec2(0.5), vec2(vec4(0.5), 0.5));`

Comment: You asked for a recommendation for math for 3d I'd recommend [this](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpt from [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

---

Casting a higher-dimensional vector to a lower-dimensional vector is also achieved with these constructors:

```
vec4 a = vec4(-1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 1.0);
vec3 b = vec3(a); // = vec3(-1.0, 2.5, 4.0)
vec2 c = vec2(b); // = vec2(-1.0, 2.5)
```

Casting a lower-dimensional vector to a higher-dimensional vector is achieved by supplying these constructors with the correct number of components:

```
vec2 a = vec2(0.1, 0.2);
vec3 b = vec3(0.0, a); // = vec3(0.0, 0.1, 0.2)
vec4 c = vec4(b, 1.0); // = vec4(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0)
```

---

So basically...
`vec2(0.5, vec4(0.5))` works because after the first argument, 0.5, there is still one argument left to insert from the vec4.

`vec2(vec4(0.5), 0.5)` doesn't work, because the 2 arguments for the vec2 call are populated from the first 2 elements of the vec4, meaning there are no more arguments to populate, so the last 0.5 has nowhere to go.

The better way to do it would be.. 
`vec2(0.5, myvec4.x)` and `vec2(myvec4.x, 0.5)`

Comment: Thanks, 2pha that makes sense. Any resource recommendations for learning math related to 3D graphics?

Comment: When I was trying to learn GLSL with three.js, I created a blog post with all my experiments [here](https://2pha.com/blog/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial/). It is a bit old, but may be of some use to you.